# Enscroll js scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used "`enscroll`" js scroll bar in my page. http://enscrollplugin.com/#demos

```
<div id="enscroll_name">
    <ul>
    <li id="p1">product1</li>
    <li id="p2">product2</li>       
    <li id="p3">product3</li>
    <li id="p4">product4</li>
    <li id="p5">product5</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

On Page load the product3 need to be in the visible area. I used  `<a name="p3"></a>` for this. But in query how to achieve this? In html we used anchor name tag like `<a name="p3"></a>`. But in this script how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.scrollTop()` jquery function to visible whatever the area that you want inside the `div`.
Try like this..

```
$('#yourdiv').scrollTop($("p[name='p2']").height());
```

Check the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hY64r/233/)

Comment: I have changed the p tag to div and name to id. Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hY64r/235/ but it is not working. Please let me know.

Comment: I have fixed it with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Just only change the way that referring the element. Use `$("#p4")` instead of using `$("p[name='p2']")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tried it. Its working good. Thanks.